# A good website that tracks reverse dependencies of Java Jar files

Tags: java, jar, dependencies

Can anyone recommend me a site that tracks the metadata of Jar files including reverse-dependencies?

To let you know what a reverse-dependencies are; Reverse dependencies of a given-jar are the jars that use the given-jar. For example, plexus-utils is a dependency of maven-core. That makes maven-core a reverse-dependency of plexus-utils.

I know there are sites that tracks the dependencies of jars. But I need a site that tracks reverse-dependencies. Thanks.

Comment: Given the _dependencies_, you should be able to retrieve the _reverse dependencies_, or do I miss anything?

Comment: retrieve how? It should be noted that for a given jar, there will be several reverse-dependencies.

Comment: I believe _dependent_ or _dependents_ might make for a better term.

Comment: @AlistairIsrael Sure. I used reverse-deps because it's the word we use in our work.

Comment: Fair enough—now, to help steer the discussion: are you looking to track *all* (as in, open source *and* proprietary/in-house) projects that depend on a particular dependency? Or do you just need this tracking for your own artifacts?

Comment: Open-source projects. I'm NOT looking for this for statistical purposes. But rather to identify the significance of some packages. Specifically currently I was looking for wagon-ftp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest site you'll find is probably one of the Maven repositories (such as http://mvnrepository.com/). An example of such a link in there is http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1, which shows you a list of some of the other artifacts that depend on xerces.

It wouldn't be a bad idea to build one dedicated to this task, but typically this is information that is hard to centralize. It is very similar to the [Debian packages website](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) or CPAN for Perl: because directories like that are central distribution points for many packages they can do a reasonable job of determining reverse dependencies, but given that there is no real official central distribution point for JAR files it is much harder to do.

Comment: I'd like to have a mechanism to view the rev-deps for a given jar but not specific for a version as well. Here, I have to click through every version to find out the rev-deps. Anyway, it's much close. Thanks for the answer.